# init doesn't kill zombies

Tags: linux, init, zombie

I have some zombie processes on my system. I've killed the parent of those zombies hoping init will take over and free up the resources (lots of sockets in CLOSE_WAIT). However init is not removing those proceses from the system:

```
#ps ax
...
17051 ?        Zl   8498:24 [impalad] <defunct>
...

# ps -o ppid= -p 17051
    1
```

Is there a way to remove the zombies without rebooting?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried `kill -s SIGCHLD 1`. It didn't help.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11172/how-can-i-kill-a-defunct-process-whose-parent-is-init

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot kill a defunct process. In someone else's words:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/suse-opensuse-60/howto-kill-defunct-processes-574612/

> You cannot kill a defunct process (a.k.a zombie) as it is already
>   dead. It doesn't take any resources so it's no big deal but if you
>   really want it to disappear form the process table you need to have
>   its parent procees reaping it. "pstree" should give you the process
>   hierarchy and "kill -1 " is sometimes enough for the job.

Because your process's parent pid is init (1), you can't do anything except reboot.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11172/how-can-i-kill-a-defunct-process-whose-parent-is-init

> You cannot kill a  (zombie) process as it is already dead.
>   The only reason why the system keeps zombie processes is to keep the
>   exit status for the parent to collect. If the parent does not collect
>   the exit status then the zombie processes will stay around forever.
>   The only way to get rid of those zombie processes are by killing the
>   parent. If the parent is init then you can only reboot.

I can't test this, but this guy says you can get rid of a defunct process like so:

[What is a zombie process and how do I kill it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12503/what-is-a-zombie-process-and-how-do-i-kill-it?rq=1)

```
There is already an accepted answer, however: you CAN kill the zombie process. Attach with the debugger to the parent process and call waitpid function. E.g.: - let's assume that the parent has PID=100, the zombie process has PID=200

$ gdb -p 100
(gdb) call waitpid(200, 0, 0)
(gdb) quit
```

This guy had a problem with a defunct process that seemed to continue running. I don't understand, but here's the link. In this case `kill -9 pid` is claimed to work.

[Zombie processes still alive and working fine, but can't be killed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/591333/zombie-processes-still-alive-and-working-fine-but-cant-be-killed)

Comment: I'm not trying to kill a zombie. I'm trying to free up the resources it occupies.

Comment: It occupies no resources. It's not even a process. Add you did ask how to "remove a zombie".

Comment: @facha see my answer, at the bottom, about gdb

Comment: lsof shows it has thousands of open files (most of them are sockets in CLOSE_WAIT). I've reached the limit of open files for that particular user and cannot launch any other processes as that user.

Comment: @facha What's that for?

Comment: Would it be safe to attach to init (pid 1) with gdb?

Comment: @facha I wouldn't do it on a serious production server... I have no idea what will happen. A reboot would be more predictable. As far as defunct processes go, anything you lookup about them will say they cannot hold file descriptors open so I don't know what's going on with your server.

Comment: @facha This guy was having a similar problem. I didn't read it all. http://serverfault.com/questions/591333/zombie-processes-still-alive-and-working-fine-but-cant-be-killed Did you every try `kill -9 pid`?